# Javascript Replace by Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, slug

I am using RegExp to make slug. I am saying replace all chars does not match the pattern like this:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('[^a-z0-9-]','g'), '');
```

It works but I need to ask if it is correct way/syntax/approach?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You can do that, or `str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g), '');`

Comment: the last hyphen is also wrong - `'*&%^$--kjhkhkjh'.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');`

Comment: @epoch in which one last hypen is wrong?

Comment: hyphens are special characters within character classes, it should be escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can write

```
new RegExp('[^a-z0-9-]','g')
```

as

```
/[^a-z0-9-]/g
```

The regular expression you wrote stands for the following:

2) Whatever is inside **[]** means any of the characters not a sequence but when **[^]** the circumflex is present at the beginning it means **NOT IN**

3) `a-z` stands for all characters from a to z (lowercase alphabet)

4) `0-9` means 0 to 9 and the hyphen (-) at the end... well a hyphen.

Therefore, what characters do you want to keep? If you want to keep only alpha-numeric then use `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g` (this is the case sensitive version) or `/[^a-z0-9]/gi` for case insensitive

the modifiers/flags: `g` = global, `i`= case insensitive

A good place to look at: [Mozilla MDN RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: While this is basically a good answer you may want to consider a better formatting, for example using more code-blocks (among other things), to increase the readability and thus making it an even better answer. :-)

Comment: @BastiM thanks for the advice. Hope this formatting helps. To be honest, I haven't explored the formatting options and I didn't know what could be done or not besides just adding code on new a new line with four characters indent.

Comment: Looks much better now :) Over time you'll explore all those formatting things and you'll get used to them.

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato Thanks for answer. Maybe this is another question but basically with the first style, can we add "but first character should be an alpha. It can't be 0-9 or '-'."?

Comment: for the same rule above but the firs char must be an alpha?

Comment: @YahyaE Just add another [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (you may want to read up on that :) ) in the first spot, allowing only chars.

Comment: @YahyaE The regexp for what you ask is `/^[^a-z][^a-z0-9-]*/gi` as @BastiM said you are discarding the first spot with the `^[^a-z]` the circumflex at the very beginning of the expression stands for the beginning of a line.

Comment: @YahyaE I think you could try this one instead:
`str.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]*/gi, '').replace(/[^a-z]?([a-z0-9-])/i,'$1');`

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato Thanks for comments `new RegExp('^[^a-z][^a-z0-9-]','g')` is not working. In anyway I need to do it with `new RegExp()'`.

Comment: @YahyaE this should do the trick: `src = src.replace(new RegExp("[^a-z0-9-]*","gi"), "").replace(new RegExp("[^a-z]?([a-z0-9-])","i"),"$1");`

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato Yes, does it.. Thank you so much. For anyone's future reference : http://jsfiddle.net/yahyaerturan/kwd8D/